# MODX-like template variables with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, modx

what would be the most appropriate way to archieve something like the [template variables](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Template+Variables) of MODX in Wordpress? Is it even possible?

It should be possible to attach custom fields to custom post types and it must have to ability to add different media types (String, Int, Boolean, Image, URL, etc.) to the posts. The entered data would have to be validated and there shouldn't be a need to enter the field names manually (as with WP's regular [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ and more - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/custom-field

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I was looking for a way do do this without plugins  since this is core content functionality. Meanwhile I doubt this is possible in WP, however, and the plugin still looks pretty nice.